# In Debian 10 what is the proper virtual package to install to get the latest kernel?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, package-management

I am attempting to `debootstrap` a Debian 10 onto a disk that will be used with an APU2D4 board.

However, I am getting stuck selecting the proper kernel package.

Assuming the architecture is the same on my host (which runs `debootstrap`) and on the target host, will `apt-get install linux-image-$(dpkg --print-architecture)` (assuming Bash semantics) install the correct kernel? ... or is there another virtual package that is even architecture-agnostic and - perhaps - uses `$(dpkg --print-architecture)` internally to figure out the appropriate *specific* kernel package?

NB: I am definitely looking for *some virtual package* so that I will always get the latest kernel updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APU2D4 is an `amd64` system, so the appropriate kernel meta-package is `linux-image-amd64`. In this instance the last part matches the architecture, but that’s not always the case; see [the `linux-latest` package](https://tracker.debian.org/linux-latest) for details of all the available kernel meta-packages.

To ensure you always get the latest kernel, once `linux-image-amd64` is installed, you should always upgrade with `apt upgrade` or `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs` so that kernel ABI changes are handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Isn't `apt-get upgrade --with-new-pkgs` pretty much equivalent to saying `apt-get dist-upgrade`, though?

Comment: Not quite: `dist-upgrade` will install new packages and remove packages if necessary to perform the upgrade; `upgrade --with-new-pkgs` will only install new packages, it won’t remove any.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes. `apt-get install linux-image-$(dpkg --print-architecture)` will install a metapackage that has a dependency on the latest kernel for the given architecture. <strike>The .deb package format has no way to specify architecture specific dependencies.</strike>